# Exception when trying to run corda

Tags: java, corda

I'm trying to run sample cordapp-example code by cloning from Github repository using:

```
git clone https://github.com/corda/samples
```

I followed all the steps as mentioned in the documentation for running the application from IntelliJ.

```
[ERROR] 14:54:18,832 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Driver shutting down because of exception [errorCode=1crywct, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/1crywct]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start notaries. A required port might be bound already.
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.start(DriverDSLImpl.kt:390) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImplKt.genericDriver(DriverDSLImpl.kt:1048) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver(Driver.kt:185) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
    at com.example.test.NodeDriverKt.main(NodeDriver.kt:15) ~[test/:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1771) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt:172) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.utilities.KotlinUtilsKt.getOrThrow(KotlinUtils.kt:134) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl.start(DriverDSLImpl.kt:379) ~[corda-node-driver-4.3.jar:?]
    ... 3 more
[WARN] 14:54:19,251 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.InternalTestUtils. - Been polling address localhost:10040 to bind for 60 seconds...
[INFO] 14:54:57,702 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 10512 msec
[INFO] 14:54:58,015 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10040], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH], platformVersion=5, serial=1578902078740), WebAddress: localhost:10043

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I see this description:

```
[ERROR] 14:13:50,501 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Driver shutting down because of exception [errorCode=1crywct, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/1crywct]
```

Has anyone else seen this before and are there any recommendations to fixing the issue or clues as to how we can debug it further?

Comment: There will be logs in the directory of the notary that the `DriverDSL` is starting. The location of the Notary should be output to console. Using that information, you should be able to get a better understanding into why it won't start.

Comment: Samples repo has many projects, which one are you trying to run? And how are you running it?

Comment: @AdelRustum
I'm trying to run "cordapp-example" and step by step as https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-the-example-cordapp-from-intellij

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, I'd see this:

```
"Unable to start notaries. A required port might be bound already"
```

which means that the port(s) used by notary is being used by other application, or, most likely being used by another running notary.

How to fix?

Open node.conf in your notary folder, and check the ports listed, such as

```
address : "localhost:10006"
```

then check the ports usage in you system, either kill the running process or change the port in notary node.conf and run again.

Good luck.